# Why are there ghost images of objects just out of focus

Tags: vision, human-eye

I have observed an interesting phenomena with my vision lately. I just think I have never reflected over this before but it might always have been this way.

I am nearsighted and have no problem with double vision as long as an object is in focus, either with or without glasses.

However when I take my glasses off and look at, e.g. my phone screen, and push it slowly just out of focus, there is a phase where multiple distorted weak ghost images appear before everything just becomes a more Gaussian like blur. It is especially clear with bright lines on a dark surface.

I do not believe that there is anything else wrong with my eyes, since as soon as an object is in a range where I can focus on it, all ghosting disappears.

I am interested in knowing if anyone else observes this.

But more interesting is what are the possible optical properties of the eye that contributes to this, or is it a property of how our brain processes the input from the eyes.

Comment: Could you generalize this question? Personal questions are discouraged here as this site is meant to answer questions of value to the community. If you can show this phenomenon is not only applicable to you, it is of interest here. Note I am happy to look into this :) In addition, personal medical questions are discouraged as we strongly urge folks to seek professional help. Until edited, therefore, I vote toclose this question. A +1 for the exciting topic though. If you reply to this post, ping me by using @AliceD, please.

Comment: I think it is a general question about the phenomenon. I just had to describe what I have observed. I am not looking for a diagnosis, I want to know the reason for what I have observed

Comment: @AliceD I agree with the OP that this is not a personal medical question but rather one asking about how the eye itself works.

Comment: @terdon agreed, but its too specific slash anecdotal to my taste

Comment: @AliceD All interesting questions and later scientific progress starts with one persons observation. This is not the same as Anecdotal evidence, since I do not claim that caise A leads to effect B. I an just asking for the reason why an observation is as it is.

Comment: @AxelOmega - yes of course, the question is whether that sort of question fits this site . I started a discussion on meta actually